# ActiveAdmin - custom page actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to create a custom page with a controller action in ActiveAdmin. I need a form on this page that checks if the phone number exists and output a list of records with this telephone.
I have the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Phone' do
  page_action :check, method: :post do
    @resources = Telephone.where(number: params[:number]).
      joins(:phoneable).map(&:phoneable)
  end

  # A form for #check action
end
```

But no idea what to do next. How to render the form properly (I would prefer to use AA DSL, rather than rendering a partial)? How to define routes?

Comment: i think you have to create partial to do what you want.

Comment: How would I define routes in case of this page? Whats the best way to define my own controller actions and view for a page in admin?